# Paste from clipboard in vim script

Tags: clipboard, paste, vim

I want to write a vim function that includes pasting from the clipboard (windows if it matters)

I think it should be something like

```
function MyPastingFunc()
  "+p  "paste from clipboard
  "do more stuff
endfunction
```

Of course the "+p is just a comment in the .vim file.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `:normal` command:

```
function MyPastingFunc()
  "paste from clipboard
  normal! "+p
  "do more stuff
endfunction
```

The `!` is used to prevent vim also running user mappings that might be part of `"+p`.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to past into a new line you can use the `:put` command, e.g:

```
:put +      will paste after the current line
:put! +     will paste before the current line
:123 put +  will paste after line 123
```

N.B. it will also move the cursor position to the first non-blank character of the inserted text.  This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the feedkeys function, whose name is pretty self-explanatory:

```
function MyPastingFunc()
    call feedkeys("\"+p")  "paste from clipboard
    "do more stuff
endfunction
```

Comment: this solution works just as well as the "correct" answer but I feel normal is better than feedkeys